# Solutions for using different versions of a library with Cocoapods (specifically:IOSLinkedInAPI and RestKit)

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, cocoapods, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to use IOSLinkedInAPI and RestKit cocoa pods. Cocoa pod is installed and I have a the Podfile set up, and I'm trying to get both of these pods working together.

RestKit requires:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.23.1'
```

while IOSLinkedInAPI requires:

```
pod 'IOSLinkedInAPI', '~> 2.0.0'
```

when I do "pod install" I get an error saying:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.0)` required by `RestKit/Network (0.23.1)`- `AFNetworking (>= 2.0.0)` required by `IOSLinkedInAPI (2.0.0)`
```

Have any of you encountered this before? What might you suggest?

Comment: Any solution on this yet?

Comment: I had to rewrite the pod to work with AFNetworking 1.3. It was a small hassle, but doable, unless you need 2.0 for another cocaopod. It's sloppy and I never found a longterm solution. Unfortunately I am no longer with that project and don't have permission to share my code. (On another note, I might advise looking for another library to use other then restKit because I heard a while back they are going to stop future work on the library.)

Comment: I ended up adding TRAutocompleteView manually (from their Github page) because I saw that it has the code to work with AFNetworking 2.0 (hence the "#ifdef AFNETWORKING2"s). I don't know why the haven't updated the pods though.

Comment: Version 0.35 of Cocoapods got this resolved and therefore, it shouldn't happen again. [check link](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.35/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Because of the way that C based languages work this would produce a duplicate symbol error. The library would have to update their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bundler which is a simple and powerful dependency manager for Ruby gems like Cocoapods. You can check more detail how to implement and configure it etc here,
https://bundler.io/